# How to prevent ajax from running multiple instances of the same php file?

Tags: php, ajax

I am aiming to make a php file that handles up to 10'000 posts per minute from ajax. I would like some insight on whether my method is good or if there's a better way to handle so many post requests. I can think of a number of problems with my code.

The javascript is actively subscribed to a streamer that sends post information to my javascript, and from there I want to send the post data to a php file that will first place the data in to an array, and secondly, each minute, send the information gathered in to a mysql table.

So I have to make sure of a few things. Firstly, that the ajax function only uses the same instance of the php file, and doesn't run multiple instances. This will make sure that all the data goes in to the same php array for mysql transferrence. Also, that data information doesn't get messed up, so I have to ID my data variables in php some way that actually works. And thirdly, because I'm using a while loop, I have to have a successful way to close the loop once instantiated.

Here is my js:

```
subscription.addListener
    (
        onItemUpdate: function (updateInfo) 
        {
            // Lightstreamer published some data
            var epic = updateInfo.getItemName().split(":")[1];
            updateInfo.forEachField
            (
                function (fieldName, fieldPos, value) //foreach epic
                {
                    $.ajax
                    (
                        {
                             data: 
                             {
                                 epic: epic, 
                                 fieldName: fieldName, 
                                 price: value
                             },
                             type: 'POST',
                             url: 'compiler_and_send_to_mysqli.php',
                             success: function(data) 
                             {
                                  alert(data);
                             }
                        }
                    );
                }
            )
        }
   );
```

Here is my php:

```
$i = 0
if(isset($_POST['data']))
{
    $i = $i + 1;
    $data[$i] = $_POST['data'];
}
if (empty($current_time)) //set the original time for the while loop 
{
    // get current date time initally keep the php instance running 
    // continuously (until the seesion closes?) in format: '2018:09:12-12:11:20';
}
while($current_time != '2099:01:01-01:01:01') //keeps php loop running for more ajax posts.
{
    $hour = date('s'); 
    if($hour == '00') // tests each minute, limits loop to 1 minute
    {
        $array[$set_for_mysqli] = $array_[$inserting_into];
        $array_[$inserting_into] = array(); //empty array
        // insert $array[$set_for_mysqli]; in mysqli dbase
        $array[$set_for_mysqli]; = array(); //empty array
        // break loop 
    }
    else
    {
        // insert $data[$i] from ajax post in to php $array_[$inserting_into];
        $data[$i] = unset($data[$i]);
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. In this scenario would AJAX run multiple instances of the php file or would it use the same instance 10'000 times per minute?
2. If it's running posts so fast, would the php variables get mixed up, e.g. by the time the first $data[$i] reaches the insert stage at the bottom of the code, might it now contain data from a second post (if the ajax posts were say, within 0.000001 seconds of each other)?
3. Is there a better way to approach handling 10'000 ajax posts and what does that code look like?
4. Should I be using a sessions?
5. Would there be a point to use memcache?

Thanks.

Comment: Yea. The js I included is the only js part that actually posts to php. The rest not shown is lightstreamer.js and lightstreamer-node.js, which creates the code used to make subscriptions to a server which is posting market data thousands of times per minute.

Comment: Is is not good to run a php process for more than a minute?

Comment: Would it be better to do this, and run it a minute at a time like a web service described in that article: `while($current_time != '1 minute in the future')?`

Comment: Because I want to amalgamate the 10'000 posts in to minute-timed data; so of the actual posts, the data will then be calculated in to an average price per minute, and then that price per minute is then sent to the database. Is it better to have the php file loaded in a session, and run a cron job that empties that array in to the database, and deletes the session, then creates a new one?